# Fechas en python

Tags: python-3.x, django, date, pdf, djangorestframework

estoy trabajando con python Django y necesito optener crear los datos de fecha en el momento de generar un pdf, estoy usando la funcion

```
    year = datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.now().strftime("%B") // mes en letras
    day = datetime.now().day
```

El dia me lo entrega en numeros por ejemplo 27 pero necesito que este en letras asi 'veintisiete', es esto posible con alguna usando strftime u otro complemento de esta funcion

Gracias por su atencion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los módulos estándar que vienen con Python no tienen esa funcionalidad, pero siempre hay algún módulo de terceros que hace lo que buscas. En este caso se trata de `num2words`.

Ejemplo:

```
from num2words import num2words
from datetime import datetime

print(num2words(datetime.now().day, lang="es"))
print(num2words(datetime.now().day, lang="es", ordinal=True))
```

---

```
veintisiete
vigésimo séptimo
```

### Bonus

Si no quieres instalar ese módulo, no es complejo escribir una función que te resuelva el problema para un rango de números reducido. En tu caso, al tratarse de fechas, todos los números son menores de 40, de modo que una función como la siguiente sería apropiada:

```
def dia_con_letras(n):
  nums = ["", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", 
          "ocho", "nueve", "diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince"]

  for limite, decenas, modulo in [(15, "", 16),
                                  (19, "dieci", 10),
                                  (20, "veinte", 20),
                                  (29, "venti", 20),
                                  (30, "treinta", 30),
                                  (39, "treinta y", 30)]:
    if n<=limite:
      return "{}{}".format(decenas, nums[n%modulo])
```

Demostración:

```
print(", ".join(dia_con_letras(n) for n in range(1,32)))
```

---

```
uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez, 
once, doce, trece, catorce, quince, dieciseis, diecisiete, dieciocho, 
diecinueve, veinte, ventiuno, ventidos, ventitres, venticuatro, 
venticinco, ventiseis, ventisiete, ventiocho, ventinueve, treinta, 
treinta yuno
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto con num2words .